# IE8 self closing tags automatically

Tags: html, magento, tags

Ok I'm trying to debug my layout and see why it's all funky in IE8 and below.. well when I start observing the code, I realize all the wrapping elements of inner elements are self closing themselves.

```
<section id="top-bar"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
      <p>ELEMENTS</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="rivets"/>
</section/>
```

Well I have styling applied to the #top-bar in my CSS:

```
#top-bar {
  background: #146c7e url('../images/top-bar-bg.png') repeat top left;
  color: #fff;
}
```

So in IE8 and below that style is not being applied. This is absolutely frustrating. This only happens to me in Magento.. All my other layouts I did on my own never self closed themselves if content wasn't directly inside of them.

Ok people thought I was self adding those ending tags, but here is my code:

```
<section id="top-bar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span7">
                    <a href="#" class="tab">Shoppe</a>
                    <a href="#" class="tab">Local</a>
                    <a href="#" class="tab">Half Baked</a>
                </div>
                <div class="span5 mag-links">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="rivets"></div>
    </section>
```

IE8 is adding those tags AUTOMATICALLY. I can't delete them.. hence the code works great in Chrome, Firefox, IE9 and up.. But IE8 and below, it starts that self-closing stuff. I NEVER had this problem before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is happening because IE8 does not support HTML5 tags, like `section`.  If you want to get this to work in IE8, call the following in the head of your document:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script>
    document.createElement('header');
    document.createElement('nav');
    document.createElement('section');
    document.createElement('article');
    document.createElement('aside');
    document.createElement('footer');
    document.createElement('hgroup');
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```

This tells IE8 to create these elements, and it should be able to recognize them as HTML elements afterwards.

Comment: It's not because of HTML5, it does it to my DIV in my example I posted as well.

Comment: You were right. I forgot to add my block I do to every website I code:
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

Comment: It's not because of HTML5. It does it to empty divs.

Comment: PRO THUG ANSWER FOR CODE GANGSTERISM

Answer (score 1):

I know you have marked the correct answer in this specific case but this may help others:

When I have these issues I open the page in Firefox, click 'View page source' and then inspect this for any red elements. This shows any code which is not closed properly (usually a missing `</div>`) and points out where it has tried to fix it for you.

Modern browsers try and close incorrect code automatically which can be annoying, as you only realise something is up when a client points it out in an old version of IE!

Hopefully this helps someone else who thinks their problem is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your `#top-bar` element doesn't contain the other elements, so you can't see a background of an element that doesn't have any size.

Change this:

```
<section id="top-bar"/>
```

to:

```
<section id="top-bar">
```

Comment: That's how it looks in my code.. maybe I wasn't clear. IE8 is adding those automatically in my code...