# IE 8 Automatically Closing <header> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, internet-explorer

#### Background

I am currently working on the final QA of a *responsive* website and I'm having an issue with IE 8 and IE 7. My client deals with government contracting so their website needs to be compatible with IE 8 and IE 7. I am using Modernizr with html5shiv built in. I am loading Modernizr in the **footer** of a WordPress theme that was custom built for this project. I'm not missing a doctype or any other obvious code.

I am using the following scripts, all of which are loaded in the footer of WordPress:

- jQuery 1.10.1
- [Modernizr 2.6.3 (click for config)](http://modernizr.com/download/#-fontface-backgroundsize-borderimage-borderradius-boxshadow-flexbox-flexboxlegacy-hsla-multiplebgs-opacity-rgba-textshadow-cssanimations-csscolumns-generatedcontent-cssgradients-cssreflections-csstransforms-csstransforms3d-csstransitions-canvas-canvastext-draganddrop-audio-video-input-inputtypes-localstorage-postmessage-sessionstorage-websockets-geolocation-inlinesvg-svg-touch-webgl-shiv-cssclasses-addtest-prefixed-teststyles-testprop-testallprops-hasevent-prefixes-domprefixes-css_remunit-css_scrollbars-mathml-load)
- respond.js 1.3.0
- superfish
- jQuery Waypoints 2.0.3
- jQuery Waypoints Sticky 2.0.3

#### The Situation

I'm having an issue with IE 8 automatically closing a `<header>` tag. First, I have used two utilities to check this issue:

1. IETester
2. IE 11 emulated to IE 8 w/ IE 8 User agent

Here is the **correct output**

```
<div class="wrapper main-header">
    <header class="container">
        <div class="sixteen columns alpha omega">
            <div class="eight columns alpha omega logo"> <a href="http://example.com"><img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/logo.png" alt="Example"></a> </div>
            <div class="wrapper main-navigation desktop">
                <nav id="nav" class="six columns alpha omega">
                    ...
                </nav>
                <div class="eight columns alpha omega overlay" style="display: none;">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="two columns alpha omega menu-ss">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div><!-- .wrapper.main-navigation --> 
        </div><!-- /.sixteen.columns --> 
    </header><!--/header-->
</div><!-- /.main-header -->
```

What IE 8 is rendering:

```
<div class="wrapper main-header">
    <header class="container"></header>
        <div class="sixteen columns alpha omega">
            <div class="eight columns alpha omega logo"> <a href="http://example.com"><img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/logo.png" alt="Example"></a> </div>
            <div class="wrapper main-navigation desktop">
                <nav id="nav" class="six columns alpha omega">
                    ...
                </nav>
                <div class="eight columns alpha omega overlay" style="display: none;">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="two columns alpha omega menu-ss">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div><!-- .wrapper.main-navigation --> 
        </div><!-- /.sixteen.columns --> 
    </header><//header><!--/header-->
</div><!-- /.main-header -->
```

#### What I have Tried

- Loading html5shiv with IE conditional in the `<head>`
- Loading Modernizr in the `<head>`

I have looked at these Stackoverflow questions/answers:

- [html 5 tags foorter or header in ie 8 and ie 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680929/html-5-tags-footer-or-header-in-ie-8-and-ie-7)
- [html5 not rendering header tags in ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891543/html5-not-rendering-header-tags-in-ie)
- [IE 8 self closing tags automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086885/ie8-self-closing-tags-automatically)

Any assistance with this is greatly appreciated! I would really *really* ***really*** like to finish this website over the weekend. I've been banging my head against a wall for the past few hours over this issue.

#### Update

Here are some images from browsershack to cut out the emulation. I tested the site virtually with Windows 7 and WIndows XP (IE 8 & IE 7). http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/0d7c1d6dd22927c20495e67f07afe8934957b4d1

Comment: Similar kind of issue is discussed here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086885/ie8-self-closing-tags-automatically

Comment: I tried the dom modifications with no avail. Thanks for the assistance though!

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to [use a VM with an actual instance of IE8](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575). I've spent hours chasing down bizarre issues that don't really exist but manifest when running IEx as IE8. It's probably *not* going to fix your problem, but worth testing and knowing for sure.

Comment: Commendable recommendation, I used browserstack.com and I am still seeing the same issue on Windows 7 and Windows XP VM with IE 8. Any other recommendations?

Comment: Can you give some hint on how it is the browser which **"renders"** the HTML code snippets you show. The confusion (and by this obstacle to better address your problem) is that with the term render I do mean take *HTML* source and make(=render) it into a website displayed in the browser video. The generation of the HTML-Source itself is not the very original thing a browser does. If at all the browser is involved in generating a source then it would be via Scripting and the DOM. If so which Scripts do you thinkis responsible for the "rendering"?

Comment: 9 out of 10 times this is caused by badly-formed HTML.  The result is that IE, in parsing, will construct the DOM with a prematurely closed tag while other browsers will often show no problems.  If this HTML is assembled in pieces it may be helpful to show the original, not result, code.  And Modernizr *does* have to be loaded in the `<head>` for the shiv to work.  Although I do not think that is the cause of the issue you're observing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I noticed is the `<nav>` element, which isnt supported in IE8.. so it makes sense that you would have to move any shims and such in the header.

Thought this might be good information as to why.

[W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp)

```
The <nav> tag is supported in Internet Explorer 9, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

Note: Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, do not support the <nav> tag.
```

Another article of interest, ([Story of the HTML5 Shiv](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/)) by Paul Irish that states **"the new elements cannot hold children and are unaffected by CSS"**, which could be why tags become self closing.  Be interested if anyone can elaborate on if this is the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for more detailed info!

Answer (score 3):

Fixed the issue by moving Modernizr, jQuery, and respond.js to the `<head>` of the DOM. Thanks for all the assistance!

Comment: you should mark this as the correct answer, so people know the question has been answered.